# Return table result in a join clause - mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, select, join

I'm trying to pull up a record from my data tables into a one dataview combining my table **emp** and **gndsale**. I have different **types** where I can get my result which can be found in gndsale(e.g, **Declared - type 22, Calculated - type 4**). In my table column **Declared**.. I can pull up the record where my type is 22, however for the **Calculated**... I have to pull up the sum of the table to get my result.

Here's my query:

```
select g.DOB
    , e.firstname
    , (select g.AMOUNT 
           from gndsale where g.type = 22 
           and g.ID IN (select e.ID from emp) 
       group by g.ID) as DECLARED 
    , ROUND(SUM(g.amount), 2) as CALCULATED 
from emp e JOIN gndsale g ON e.ID = g.ID 
where g.type = 4 GROUP BY G.ID
```

Here is the result:

[image]

I want to also get the DECLARED as well

Here is the result:

[image]

I've tried to join this and put my select statement in a select statement... but it gives me no result.
Can you help me on this? :(

Comment: please put your tables on http://sqlfiddle.com/ so we can batter understand and share the link in question

Comment: That group by is invalid. Wont execute on newer MySQL versions (unless in compatibility mode), will return unpredictable result with older versions... The general GROUP BY rule says: If a GROUP BY clause is specified, each column reference in the SELECT list must either identify a grouping column or be the argument of a set function.

Answer (score 0):

try this..... as i dont know the table structure....

```
select g.DOB
    , e.firstname
    , (select sum(isnull(g.AMOUNT,0)) 
           from gndsale where g.type = 22 
           and g.ID IN (select z.ID from emp z where z.ID=e.ID) 
       group by g.ID) as DECLARED 
    , ROUND(SUM(g.amount), 2) as CALCULATED 
from emp e JOIN gndsale g ON e.ID = g.ID 
where g.type = 4 GROUP BY G.ID
```

Answer (score -1):

I've fixed it :)
I can just use double alias (e.g gndsale a, gndsale b) on my table and determine the type :)

Comment: Query: 
SELECT a.DOB,a.Amount as DECLARED, 
SUM(c.Amount) as CALCULATED FROM gndsale a
 INNER JOIN emp b ON a.ID= b.ID 
INNER JOIN gndsale c ON b.ID= c.ID
WHERE a.type = "22" AND c.type = "4" GROUP BY b.ID